# How do I convert a REST API answer to proper XML using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to parse the logotype name used in a SharePoint site using PowerShell.

The request is simple enough:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<siteaddress>/_api/web/SiteLogoUrl -UseDefaultCredentials).content
```

which generates the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:SiteLogoUrl xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">/<sitepath>/SiteAssets/Logo_name.jpg</d:SiteLogoUrl>
```

However, trying to convert it to XML just creates "empty" data

```
[xml]((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<siteaddress>/_api/web/SiteLogoUrl -UseDefaultCredentials).Content).SiteLogoUrl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, stupid me...

```
([xml](Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<siteaddress>/_api/web/SiteLogoUrl -UseDefaultCredentials).Content).SiteLogoUrl
```

```
d      : http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices
m      : http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata
georss : http://www.georss.org/georss
gml    : http://www.opengis.net/gml
#text  : /<SITEPATH>/SiteAssets/Logo_name.jpg
```